# Java jetty servlet container fails to resolve class dependencies

Tags: java, neo4j, jetty, gremlin

```
15:28:38.716 [qtp1588771273-32] WARN  o.e.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler - /tp/gremlin/execute
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not resolve dependency of type:javax.transaction.TransactionManager
    at org.neo4j.graphdb.DependencyResolver$Adapter$1.select(DependencyResolver.java:87) ~[neo4j-kernel-2.2.9.jar:2.2.9]
    at org.neo4j.kernel.extension.KernelExtensions.resolveDependency(KernelExtensions.java:112) ~[neo4j-kernel-2.2.9.jar:2.2.9]
```

This is from Neo4j 2.x (the Gremlin plug-in).  The package, when built and deployed as instructed at https://github.com/thinkaurelius/neo4j-gremlin-plugin, *does contain* the jar-file which describes this class, and Maven *did download* it and did install it there.  But, when the server attempts to load and execute the extension, nothing is resolved.

Why?

Comment: Please note that the files as installed into the plugin directory (by Maven!) do not have specific directory-structured names.  I presume that *all* of them are somehow loaded when the extension is run, by means of magicks of which I know not.  The instructions make no discussion of $CLASSPATH, so I conclude that this is not meant to be necessary.

Comment: The following entries were found in another log:  Apr 07, 2016 8:13:23 AM com.sun.jersey.api.core.PackagesResourceConfig init
INFO: Scanning for root resource and provider classes in the packages:
  com.thinkaurelius.neo4j.plugins
Apr 07, 2016 8:13:23 AM com.sun.jersey.api.core.ScanningResourceConfig logClasses
INFO: Root resource classes found:
  class com.thinkaurelius.neo4j.plugins.GremlinPlugin
Apr 07, 2016 8:13:23 AM com.sun.jersey.api.core.ScanningResourceConfig init
INFO: No provider classes found.
... also, a Curl query of "extensions" for this neo4j server shows "none."